# XCode 9.3 WatchKit crash on WKInterfaceButton tap

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, storyboard, watchkit

A button crashes on tap (watch simulator and real device) :

> Thread 1: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** (code=1, address=0x0) inside the
>   framework/function **libswiftCore.dylib swift_getObjectType**

The button has a “`Sent Action`” defined in the `storyboard`, but no segue, other buttons work well, adding a segue to the button seems to resolve this issue. This occurs on `Xcode 9.3` ( did not occur on previous versions)

Any ideas? I want to understand whats causing the crash - hate leaving stuff unresolved.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: if not you should check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477499/watch-button-press-crash