# watch button press crash

Tags: swift, watchkit

it seems to be the same error and conditions as [this unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727620/xcode-9-3-watchkit-crash-on-wkinterfacebutton-tap), but I have more to add (its really easy to replicate)

Create a new project in the latest Xcode

iOS App with WatchKit App

Go to the  WatchKit App > Interface.storyboard and put a single button on the Interface Controller Scene > Interface Controller
[image]

Go to  WatchKit Extension > InterfaceController.swift and add a new member

```
@IBOutlet var scheduleMeetingButton: WKInterfaceButton!
```

and method

```
@IBAction func scheduleMeeting(_ sender: Any) { }
```

then go back to Interface.storyboard and link both of these to the button

launch the app (on the watch simulator)
[image]

than click the button and you will get this exec error

[image]

**What is causing this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code i would suggest updating the action function from sender: any to sender: wkinterfacebutton hope this helps!